# Remove Disable attribute if there are value on the Inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Input and submit button

```
<input type="text" name="firstName"  placeholder="Michael">
<button type="button" class="update-change" disabled="disabled">Save</button>
```

I want when someone sets focus on the input  the button will be active. So I used this:

```
$('input[name="firstName"]"]').focus(function() { 
   $(".update-change").removeAttr('disabled');
}).blur(function() {
    $(".update-change").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

and because of this When anyone click outside button become disable again. This is Good so far but I am wanting when value is given on the input save button will not become disable clicking outside of the input. but I am not sure how to do this. Use change function ?

So points are:

1. Button will be disabled very first. If click on the input it will be
     active.
2. if there is no value made on the input and click outside button will be disable.
3. But if any value has been added button will remain active. It will not make disable state.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YjE32/)** .

Thanks In advance.

Comment: add an if statement to your blur function.  if no value in the text field, then disable the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[name="firstName"]"]').focus(function() { 
   $(".update-change").removeAttr('disabled');
}).blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(".update-change").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the Short answer. and Accepted for answering first :)

Answer (score 4):

On your `.blur` function, you can check to see if it's empty. If it is, disable the button, else enable it. This will also enable the button if the focus is on the box, and disable it if focus is removed and nothing was typed in the box.

```
$('input[name="firstName"]').focus(function () {
     $(".update-change").removeAttr('disabled');
 }).blur(function () {
     if ($.trim(this.value) == "") {
         $('.update-change').attr("disabled", true);
     } else {
         $('.update-change').removeAttr("disabled");
     }
 });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EKPfq/)

Comment: Maybe I have Friday brain already, but I'm having trouble conjuring a scenario where your `else` clause is necessary.

Comment: @isherwood You're right though, it's not really needed. Your answer is cleaner, and rightfully accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use if statement to check if the input is not having any thing then you are disabling the button other wise it remain enabled. Here is working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YjE32/6/)

```
 $('input[name="firstName"]').focus(function() { 
     $(".update-change").removeAttr('disabled');
  }).blur(function() {
     if($('input[name="firstName"]').val() == ""){
         $(".update-change").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       }
 });
```